# npm ERR! 404 Not Found: har-validator@5.1.2

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, npm-install, angular7, build-definition

After upgrading to angular7 the build in azure fails on the "npm install" step.
Locally everything works fine.

I have tried:

1. Setting the clean option in the build definition to true and to "all directories".
2. Forcing an npm update "npm@latest -g" step before the install step
3. Setting the "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" on the Application Settings in Portal to the same version as I have locally (10.14.1).

But I am still getting the following error output from the "npm install" step.
(Notice that the agent is not using the same version as the default value is set to)

My last option (as I see it) is to delete the entire service and create a new one with the same name - but I would like to avoid that..

Regarding the last error in the output (**npm ERR! 404 Not Found: har-validator@5.1.2**), I have no idea what this is but it is not included in my package.json. I believe it might be something the cli packages is using?

```
2018-12-11T21:46:07.1672265Z ##[section]Starting: npm install
2018-12-11T21:46:07.1675810Z ==============================================================================
2018-12-11T21:46:07.1675868Z Task         : npm
2018-12-11T21:46:07.1675929Z Description  : Run an npm command
2018-12-11T21:46:07.1675961Z Version      : 0.2.27
2018-12-11T21:46:07.1675996Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-12-11T21:46:07.1676309Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613746)
2018-12-11T21:46:07.1676342Z ==============================================================================
2018-12-11T21:46:07.7212998Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" config list"
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4985558Z ; cli configs
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4985985Z metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4986124Z scope = ""
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4986277Z user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v10.13.0 win32 x64"
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4986429Z 
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4986565Z ; environment configs
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4986753Z cache = "C:\\npm\\cache"
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4986863Z prefix = "C:\\npm\\prefix"
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4986958Z 
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4987093Z ; builtin config undefined
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4987188Z 
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4987354Z ; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4987583Z ; cwd = D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4987728Z ; HOME = C:\Users\VssAdministrator
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4987911Z ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
2018-12-11T21:46:25.4988084Z 
2018-12-11T21:46:25.5112108Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" install"
2018-12-11T21:47:30.4103336Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\uglify-es-2690efe8\package.json'
2018-12-11T21:47:30.5364487Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\uglify-es-2690efe8\LICENSE'
2018-12-11T21:47:30.6517880Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\uglify-es-2690efe8\README.md'
2018-12-11T21:47:30.8043664Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\ajv-dc7fc88a\lib\.DS_Store'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.0212461Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\webpack-subresource-integrity-6d084f0d\examples\webpack4-contenthash-issue-83\README.md'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.0214504Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\ajv-dc7fc88a\lib\ajv.d.ts'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.1252776Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\webpack-subresource-integrity-6d084f0d\examples\webpack4-contenthash-issue-83\index.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.1989574Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\ajv-dc7fc88a\lib\ajv.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.3153484Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\webpack-subresource-integrity-6d084f0d\examples\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.4413192Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\ajv-dc7fc88a\lib\cache.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.4418678Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\moment-b4a9e1a1\src\lib\parse\regex.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.6315506Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\node-gyp-6d42b3cc\gyp\tools\Xcode\Specifications\gyp.pbfilespec'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.6315920Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\moment-b4a9e1a1\src\lib\parse\token.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.6432211Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\body-parser-5b44689c\lib\types\json.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.6516115Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\node-gyp-6d42b3cc\gyp\tools\Xcode\Specifications\gyp.xclangspec'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.6572566Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\unique-filename-a895a9ae\coverage\__root__\index.html'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.6605443Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\json-schema-traverse-23dbd864\spec\fixtures\schema.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.7477508Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\unique-filename-a895a9ae\coverage\__root__\index.js.html'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.7575572Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\body-parser-5b44689c\lib\types\raw.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.7740463Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-cli-3421191e\src\ngtsc\host\src\reflection.d.ts'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.7761304Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\json-schema-traverse-23dbd864\spec\index.spec.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.7898919Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\body-parser-5b44689c\lib\types\text.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.8368271Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@angular\compiler-cli-3421191e\src\ngtsc\host\src\reflection.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.8425215Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\body-parser-5b44689c\lib\types\urlencoded.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.9064194Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\components\datalist\datalist.d.ts'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.9116674Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\components\datalist\datalist.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.9175038Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\components\datalist\datalist.js.map'
2018-12-11T21:47:31.9218406Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\components\datalist\datalist.metadata.json'
2018-12-11T21:47:32.0569111Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\components'
2018-12-11T21:47:32.6149587Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e876628d\src\libsass\src\utf8\checked.h'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.6779419Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\components\gmap\gmap.d.ts'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.6899685Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\components\gmap\gmap.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7021864Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\components\gmap\gmap.js.map'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7105126Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\components\gmap\gmap.metadata.json'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7420473Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@angular\common-66e6ce23\esm5\src\pipes\deprecated\date_pipe.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7477117Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@angular-devkit\schematics-b141a7e4\tasks\tslint-fix\test\rules\customRuleRule.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7574105Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@angular\common-66e6ce23\esm5\src\pipes\deprecated\index.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7578418Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@angular-devkit\schematics-b141a7e4\tasks\tslint-fix\test\run-task.d.ts'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7583385Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@angular\common-66e6ce23\esm5\src\pipes\deprecated\intl.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7583560Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@angular-devkit\schematics-b141a7e4\tasks\tslint-fix\test\run-task.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7763116Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\tslint-63def258\lib\verify\lines.d.ts'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.7764349Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\tslint-63def258\lib\verify\lines.js'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.8244897Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-f11b263c\test\fixtures\input-directory\sass\nested\three.scss'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.8255514Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-f11b263c\test\fixtures\input-directory\sass\one.scss'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.8283952Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-f11b263c\test\fixtures\input-directory\sass\two.scss'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.8300811Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-f11b263c\test\fixtures'
2018-12-11T21:47:33.9502082Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@schematics\angular-5e588af5\universal\files\src\__main@stripTsExtension__.ts'
2018-12-11T21:47:34.9391213Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@schematics\angular-5e588af5\universal\files\src'
2018-12-11T21:47:34.9391576Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-dcf43933\esm5\src\render3\interfaces'
2018-12-11T21:47:34.9393379Z npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\src\Fightplan_v1\node_modules\.staging\primeng-e2ced65b\resources\components\toast\toast.css'
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4859640Z npm WARN @ngrx/effects@6.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4859826Z npm WARN @ngrx/entity@6.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4859978Z npm WARN @ngrx/router-store@6.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860036Z npm WARN @ngrx/router-store@6.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860119Z npm WARN @ngrx/router-store@6.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/router@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860193Z npm WARN @ngrx/store@6.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860248Z npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860313Z npm WARN @1.0.0 No description
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860359Z npm WARN @1.0.0 No repository field.
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860411Z npm WARN The package jquery is included as both a dev and production dependency.
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860686Z 
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860757Z npm ERR! code E404
2018-12-11T21:47:36.4860803Z npm ERR! 404 Not Found: har-validator@5.1.2
2018-12-11T21:47:36.5420339Z 
2018-12-11T21:47:36.5421133Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-12-11T21:47:36.5421305Z npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2018-12-11T21_47_36_496Z-debug.log
2018-12-11T21:47:36.6035543Z ##[error]npm failed with error: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd failed with return code: 1
2018-12-11T21:47:36.6062198Z ##[section]Finishing: npm install
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After doing a lot of testing I found that there was an old `package-lock.json` lying around in the application.

Deleting the `package-lock.json` and running a new build fixed the problem..

Comment: The reason is that the author of har-validator unpublished version 5.1.2 and 5.1.1: https://github.com/ahmadnassri/node-har-validator/issues/112