# error installing cypress on windows 64 with npm

Tags: npm, cypress, windows-7-x64

I'm seeing an error when attempting to install the latest [cypress](https://cypress.io) on my Windows 10 machine. I was using cypress 8.7 just fine. I deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and removed `"cypress": "^8.7.0",` from `package.json`.

Now installing cypress (9.1) I see this error:

`npm install --save-dev cypress`

> npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'har-validator'

I see the same error when trying to use the old version too
`npm install --save-dev cypress@8.7.0`

System info from powershell:

```sh
node -v
> v16.8.0

npm -v
> 7.21.0
```

**UPDATE:**

1. My friend is able to install with dependency 8.7.0 in package.json, on OSX with nodejs `14.16.0`.
2. This works today (2021-11-26) for me
   `npm install --save-dev cypress@8.7.0`

Comment: this might be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732973/npm-err-404-not-found-har-validator5-1-2

Comment: @gretal please elaborate. the only response suggest to delete `package-lock.json`. I mentioned I tried that above. A friend just confirmed cypress installs normally right now for him. I tried reboot and it still wont work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! 404 Not Found: har-validator@5.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732973/npm-err-404-not-found-har-validator5-1-2)

Comment: @MartinZeitler that was already pointed out in the comment directly above. No, it does not help. I tried the accepted answer before posting. My post clearly says I deleted `package-lock.json`. Other people succeed using other node/npm/OS - so its not a general problem or solution. I want to know why it fails for me.

Comment: @cyrf Not sure which, but some NPM packages may depend on Python 3.7 to build (which is a whole lot more likely to be already installed on Linux & OSX, than it is on Windows). Please run again with CLI option `-dd`, else it's difficult to tell why - opposite to having a log of what happened.

Comment: That [PR](https://github.com/cypress-io/request/pull/16/files) removes it altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Bug in @cypress/request.
Take a look at https://github.com/cypress-io/request/pull/15

**EDIT:** There is a PR from one of the devs. https://github.com/cypress-io/request/pull/16

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Cypress issue with latest versions. we have this problem for v8.7.0 today.  `"npm install har-validator"` manually installed the missing har-validator module, that helped.